# How to add the language selector in the ckeditor tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, activeadmin

I've integrated the `ckeditor gem` for `rails` in the `activeadmin` gem. So far it is working good but I want to include the `language selector` which I've seen in the demo of the ckeditor.  But I've not found any related article except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747678/how-to-add-a-dropdown-button-to-ckeditor-to-insert-content-when-selecting-a-drop/13747239#13747239). The demo of that selector is[this](http://ckeditor.com/demo#localization). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need to know? what is the problem? what is the error. You need to specify a little bit more? As far as i see the Article gives a example of implementation. did you look to the source code of the pages that you gave?

Comment: i want to know the procedure to add the language selector to the ckeditor? See this http://ckeditor.com/demo#localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download CKEditor and check the following sample: `samples\uilanguages.html`

Basically, CKEditor demo just shows a custom select element, with the list of languages taken from `samples/assets/uilanguages/languages.js`

The most relevant lines from this sample are:

```
<script src="assets/uilanguages/languages.js"></script>

<script>
    document.write( '<select disabled="disabled" id="languages" onchange="createEditor( this.value );">' );    
    // Get the language list from the _languages.js file.
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < window.CKEDITOR_LANGS.length ; i++ ) {
        document.write(
            '<option value="' + window.CKEDITOR_LANGS[i].code + '">' +
                window.CKEDITOR_LANGS[i].name +
            '</option>' );
    }
    document.write( '</select>' );
</script>
```

Keep in mind that by default CKEditor auto detects the browser language and loads the correct translation. So, providing a select combo to a user may so that he could select the language may not have a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah ive gone through it very before posting the problem here. Since ive to use the `ckeditor` in the `activeadmin` so it is making me mad on how to do that? Anyway as u ve told me that `ckeditor` detect the language so right now it is the only option for me since i dont know how to edit the html and put the javascript code for the language selector